# Javascript Chrome Extension Async Promise

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, promise

Fairly new to chrome extensions so in the process of creating something pretty simple with just a popup.

Everything is working fine, but I have had to use chrome.tabs.executeScript to get an array of content from the DOM (links), then idea is then to present these in the pop up. As the chrome.tabs.executeScript runs synchronously compared to the rest running async I am getting undefined errors.

To try and get around this I wrapped my chrome.tabs.executeScript call inside a promise and using the then() syntax called my subsequent functions. Unfortunately the array I am populating is still undefined so seems the promise isn't working as expected.

Don't judge the naming convention, its still WIP and everything will be tidied up.

Mainfest:

```
 {
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "One-click Kittens",
  "description": "This extension demonstrates a browser action with kittens.",
  "version": "1.1",

  "permissions": [
    "https://secure.flickr.com/",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

popup.js

```
globalThis.getText = [];

var kittenGenerator = {

    requestKittens: function () {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript({ code: `(${inContent})()` });
            resolve();
            }
        );

        function inContent() {
            const el = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
            this.getText = el;
            //DEBUG
            for (var i = 0; i < this.getText.length; i++) {
                console.log(this.getText[i]);
            }
        }
    },


  showTracks_: function (e) {
      var kittens = this.getText;
      console.log(this.getText);
      for (var i = 0; i < kittens.length; i++) {
          console.log(kittens[i]);
          var img = document.createElement('button');
          img.id = 'dl';
          img.value = kittens[i].getAttribute('src');
          img.innerText = 'Dl';
          document.body.appendChild(img);
      }
  }
};

// Run our kitten generation script as soon as the document's DOM is ready.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    kittenGenerator.requestKittens().then(kittenGenerator.showTracks_());
});
```

The idea is to grab specific audio elements from the DOM and then I can display a list of buttons in the popup.

If anyone can spot where I have gone wrong with the promises I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the outer interface of executeScript (Promise or callback), but the fact that your inContent doesn't actually return anything so `(${inContent})()` evaluates to `undefined`.

So just return something meaningful:

```js
function inContent() {
  return [...document.getElementsByTagName('audio')]
    .map(el => [el.id, el.textContent]);
}
```

The returned data must be JSON-compatible (number, string, boolean, null, and objects/arrays consisting of these types). Attempting to return a DOM element or a Promise or Map/Set will produce an empty `{}`.

Comment: So returning say "return document.getElementsByTagName('audio');" which is an array of elements in inContent should do the trick? If so the getText array is still undefined and it still seems as though the promise is being ignored

Comment: I thought you know that only `inContent` runs in the context of a content script, nothing else, which is why it can't see other non-injected functions. Also, as you can see my answer explicitly mentions that you can't return DOM elements.

Comment: I understand the disconnect between inContent running as a content script vs the extension script. Even if I take the DOM elements, put them into an array (as you stated is allowed) then still the this.getText isn't defined, my assumption is that due to the async nature its hitting that part of the code before other parts complete, hence the Promise and .then() clause. Is what I am even trying to do possible - take DOM elements and pass them into my popup.js file?

Comment: Apparently I'm very bad at explaining so I'll just try to rephrase the answer. The problem is not related to async or Promise and no, inContent does not run as the extension script: it's declared there but it doesn't run there, it runs only as a content script via executeScript. A content script runs in an entirely different page which doesn't have any of the methods defined in your extension script. You can't transfer DOM elements from the injected code to the callback of executeScript.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I now understand what I am trying to do isn't possible. I guess I will have to look into the messaging side of things and see if that works